Make both colors connected
Is it possible to rearrange the 8 rectangles shown below (only translation, no rotation or reflection) so that the red squares form a connected region and the white squares form a connected region? Rectangles cannot overlap and corner-touching does not count as connected. (The black lines show each rectangle is made up of 3 squares; they have 0 width)
Source: some math contest problem (but I forgot which one)


can red/white polygon squares be corner-touching or do they have to be side-touching?

I said corner-touching does not count as connected.

I believe this arrangement qualifies:

 


Nice symmetry, rfcrpvnyyl unys fvqr pbaarpgvba, but, white and red 'polygon' do not seem to be 'connected', or, am I misunderstanding?

@FirstNameLastName The white squares form a single connected region. The red squares also form a single connected region.

OK, fair enough, so 'connected' did not imply 'closed', which is what 'polygon' (as opposed to 'region') might suggest.

@FirstNameLastName The border of each coloured region is a polygon.

@FirstNameLastName You mean "convex" or at least "not to concave".

thanks @all my bad : I was thinking about the region itself, not it's border, as if every square was a colored pixel,
